# Skipped installing .framework binary due to the error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mixpanel, carthage

I'm using Carthage and getting this error with a dependency or two:

**Skipped installing mixpanel-swift.framework binary due to the error:** *"Incompatible Swift version - framework was built with 3.1 and the local version is 4.0."*

[image]

I understand generally what Carthage is seeing as the problem, but I haven't found a satisfactory answer on my own or looking through other issues posted that feels as clean or solid as I'm assuming it should be.

*I've seen `carthage bootstrap --platform iOS --no-use-binaries` as a potential solution, but I can't tell if thats solving the actual problem I'm having or not, or if it is the best solution long term?*

Any help on a solution or guiding me to my way there?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running carthage with --no-use-binaries? What happens?

Comment: @MikeTaverne I have tried that, sometimes it fixes things and sometimes it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you need to use the Swift 4 version of Mixpanel. It is failing because the code you are getting from Github is for Swift 3. On their Github page they say you should use the Swift 4 branch - [Mixpanel Swift 4 branch](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-swift/tree/swift4). I think your Cart file needs to use: github "mixpanel/mixpanel-swift" "swift4"